# rowaatr in jqGrid style is not applied

Tags: css, jqgrid

I'm trying to give background color to jqgrid row depending on some row value. The code that I use is given below. Also it should be mentioned that the code for table generation is locked for me and I'm adding only the jqgrid part.
The callback function in rowaatr is working as it was meant to be (used the debugger to check).
The problem is that the background color is not changing.
I have used a class and a direct style assigment with no result. Also I have used !important after color with no luck.

I'm using jqGrid 4.6.0, Firefox 31 and Chrome 37, jquery 1.10.2 and jquery-ui-1.10.3.

```
function BuildTable(airmoves) {
/* Removing previous table if exists */
  if ($('#airmovestablewrapper').get(0)){
    $('#airmovestablewrapper').remove();
  }
/* adding a table wrapper */
  $('#divsearchresults').append('<div id="airmovestablewrapper"></div>');          
  $('#airmovestablewrapper').append('<table id="tblairmoves"></table>');

  row = '<thead><tr><th>callsign</th><th>ADEP</th><th>ADEST</th><th>MoveTime</th><th>AircraftRegistration</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead>';
  $('#tblairmoves').append(row);
  for (i=0;i<airmoves.length;i++)
     {
       row = '<tr>';
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].callsign + '</td>';
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].ADEP + '</td>';
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].ADEST + '</td>';
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].MoveTime + '</td>'; 
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].AircraftRegistration + '</td>';
       row = row + '<td>' + airmoves[i].Type + '</td>';
       row = row + '</tr>';
       $('#tblairmoves').append(row);
     }   
   row = '</tbody>';
   $('#tblairmoves').append(row);
   $('#divsearchresults').append('<div id="pager"></div>');

   tableToGrid('#tblairmoves',{
     dataType: 'local',
     rowNum: 20,
     rowList: [20,30,40],
     pager: '#pager',
     height: '100%',
     width: 'autowidth',
     viewrecords: true,
     gridview: true,
     colNames:['Type','Χαρακτηριστικό', 'ADEP','ADEST','Ώρα κίνησης', 'Νηολόγιο'],
     colModel:[ 
       {name:'Type',index:'Type', width:150},
       {name:'callsign',index:'callsign', width:100}, 
       {name:'ADEP',index:'ADEP', width:50, align:'center'}, 
       {name:'ADEST',index:'ADEST', width:50, align:'center'},
       {name:'MoveTime',index:'MoveTime', width:150, align:'center'},
       {name:'AircraftRegistration',index:'AircraftRegistration', width:120, align:'center'}       
       ],
     rowattr: function (rd) 
      {
        if (rd.Type === "0") {
          //return {"style": "background-color:#F4AC91;"};
          return {"class": "arrivals"};
        }
        else {
          if (rd.Type === "1") {
            //return {"style": "background-color:#EAE69D;"};
            return {"class": "departures"};
          }
          else {
            //return {"style": "background-color:#32E69D;"};
            return {"class": "other"};
          }
        }
      },
     caption: "Κινήσεις αεροσκαφών"
   });

/* Center jqGrid caption starts */
   $("#tblairmoves").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
    .css("text-align", "center")
    .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
    .css("float", "none");
/* Center jqGrid caption ends */

$("#pager_left, #pager_center", "#pager").width(0);

/* hinding columns starts */
   $("#tblairmoves").jqGrid('hideCol','Type');
/* hinding columns ends */

/* maximum lines per screen 20 starts */
   $('#tblairmoves').setGridParam({ rowNum: 20 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
/* maximum lines per screen 20 ends */   
}
```

The used classes. I also tried .ui-widget-content in front of class with no luck again.

```
.arrivals {
  background-color: rgb(244, 172, 145);
}

.departures {
  background-color: rgb(234, 230, 157);
}

.other {
  background-color: rgb(50, 230, 157);
}
```

**Final Update**

Working function for the above problem.

```
function BuildTable1(airmoves) {
$('#tblairmoves').jqGrid('GridUnload');
jQuery("#tblairmoves").jqGrid({     
    datatype: 'local', 
    data: airmoves,
    height: '100%',
    colNames:['Type','Χαρακτηριστικό', 'ADEP','ADEST','Ώρα κίνησης', 'Νηολόγιο'], 
    colModel:[ 
       {name:'Type',index:'Type', width:150, hidden: true},
       {name:'callsign',index:'callsign', width:100}, 
       {name:'ADEP',index:'ADEP', width:50, align:'center'}, 
       {name:'ADEST',index:'ADEST', width:50, align:'center'},
       {name:'MoveTime',index:'MoveTime', width:150, align:'center'},
       {name:'AircraftRegistration',index:'AircraftRegistration', width:120, align:'center'}],
    afterInsertRow : function(rowid, data) {
      var trElement = jQuery("#"+ rowid,jQuery('#tblairmoves'));
      trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
      if (data.Type === "0") {                    
        trElement.addClass('arrivals');
      }
      else {
        if (data.Type === "1") {        
            trElement.addClass('departures');
          }
          else {            
            trElement.addClass('other');
            }
          }      
    }, 
    rowNum:20, 
    rowList:[10,20,30], 
    pager: '#pager', 
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Κινήσεις αεροσκαφών" });
  $("#pager_left, #pager_center", "#pager").width(0);
}
```

Styles

```
.arrivals {
  background-color: rgb(244, 172, 145)  !important;
  background-image: none; 
}

.departures {
  background-color: rgb(234, 230, 157)  !important;
  background-image: none; 
}

.other {
  background-color: rgb(50, 230, 157)  !important;
  background-image: none; 
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend you ever use `tableToGrid` method which is *not real part of jqGrid*. Instead of that you should create grid with `datatype: 'local'` (!!! not `dataType: 'local'`), and `data: airmoves`. You can use `hidden: true` property for `Type` column directly or don't create the column at all. The parameter of `rowattr` will still have all input properties (`Type` and all other)

Comment: Correct will be to use `data: airmoves` and add `gridview: true` option additionally. One should never use `addRowData` in the loop. If `data: airmoves` don't display anything then you should start the code with the test data in debugger. You will quickly localize the problem. By the way I could see that you modified the text of the question accidentally. Next time please write small comment to inform about new information.

Comment: Problem is solved and the working code is shown in the original question update section.
A real big thanks to Oleg for his help.

Comment: You are welcome! I don't recommend ever use `afterInsertRow` instead of that one should add `gridview:true` option and use `rowattr`. It's important additionally how you define CSS rule for the classes `arrivals` etc. Usage of `!important` is bad and should be removed too. Look [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25331772/315935).