# Jqgrid default sorting doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, sorting, jqgrid

In `Firefox & IE`, the listing display as expected and default sorting is fine. And `No.` column displaying from `1,2,3...` in ascending order

But the problem is in `Chrome` and displaying not in order (Please see my below screenshot)
[image]

Below is my code and I also tried `firstsortorder:'asc'` of relevant column model named **lineNo**, but it doesn't work.

In fact, it is about 100 records in total.

```
jQuery.post(jqDataUrl, data, function(response) {
  if(response != null) {
    jQuery("#jqTable").jqGrid("GridUnload");
    jQuery("#jqTable").jqGrid({
      data: response.rowdata,
      datatype: "local",
      colNames:
      [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "<spring:message code = "patron.transaction.number" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.pdtType" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.pdtDetails" />",
        "<spring:message code = "patron.transaction.ticketID" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.priceCat" />" ,
        "<spring:message code = "sales.priceClass" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.unitPrice" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.ticketType" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.dateFulfilled" />",
        "<spring:message code = "sales.lastStatus" />",
        "<spring:message code = "patron.transaction.lastUpdated" />",
        "<spring:message code = "generic.jqgrid.action" />"
      ],
      colModel:
      [
        { name: "txnID", index: "txnID", width: 50,hidden:true, editable: true, align: "left" ,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "isReturned", index: "isReturned", width: 50,hidden:true, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "description", index: "description", width: 50, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "lineNo", index: "lineNo", width: 50, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "pdtType", index: "pdtType", width: 100, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "pdtDetails", index: "pdtDetails", width: 100, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "ticketID", index: "ticketID", width: 100,key:true, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "priceCat", index: "priceCat", width: 100, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "priceClass", index: "priceClass", width: 100, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "unitPrice", index: "unitPrice", width: 100, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false,
          formatter:function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
             if(cellvalue == null || cellvalue == "") {
               return "";
             } else {
                 return "${userCurrency}"+parseFloat(cellvalue).toFixed(2);
             }
          }
        },
        { name: "ticketType", index: "ticketType", width: 80, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "dateFulFilled", index: "dateFulFilled", width: 80, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "lastStatus", index: "lastStatus", width: 80, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: "lastUpdated", index: "lastUpdated", width: 80, align: "left",title:false,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: 'action', index: 'action', width: 50, align: "center", sortable: false, search:false}
      ],
      autowidth: true,
      height: 'auto',
      grouping: true,
      groupingView : {
        groupField : ['description'],
        groupColumnShow : [false, false],
        groupText : ["<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>"],
        groupCollapse : false,
        groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
      },
      pager: jQuery("#jqTablePager"),
      //rowNum: 10,
      rowList: [10, 20, 30],
      cmTemplate: { title: false },
      emptyrecords:"<spring:message code = 'generic.jqgrid.nosearchresults'/>",
      jsonReader : {root: "rowdata", page: "page", total: "total", records: "records", repeatitems: false, id: "ticketID"},
      gridComplete: function() {
        var grid = jQuery("#jqTable");
        var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
          var row = ids[i];
          var isReturned = grid.getCell(row, 'isReturned');
          if(isReturned=='true'){
              document.getElementById(row).style.backgroundColor='orange';
          }
          var button = "<img class='icons' title='View Fee Details' src='<c:url value='/resources/img/view.png' />' onclick='viewFeeDetailPopup(" + row + ")'/> <img class='icons' title='View Ticket History' src='<c:url value='/resources/img/lookup2.png' />' onclick='viewTicketHistoryPopup(" + row + ")'/>";
          grid.jqGrid('setRowData', row, {action: button});
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    jQuery('#statusMsg').html("<fmt:message key="generic.jqgrid.noresponse"/>");
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated and many thanks!!!

Comment: Why the grid should be sorted by `lineNo`? You don't use any `sortname`. By the way you use `groupField : ['description']` (grouping by one column `description`), but arrays `groupColumnShow`, `groupText` and `groupOrder` contains **two** elements. Do you missed one element in `groupField` or you forgot to remove second elements in other arrays of `groupingView`? Could you provide test data which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need **add `sortname: "lineNo"` option to your grid to fix your main problem**.

Your current code have some other small problems and can be improved. Below I include the list of some small (or not so small) suggestions.

First of all you need follow the options used in [Limitations of grouping](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations) and add `gridview: true` option in the grid. If you uses the current version of jqGrid it fix the problem internally, but I recommend you do add the option explicitly.

You should remove `jsonReader` option because it will be ignored in case of `datatype: "local"`. If it's really required one can use `localReader` instead (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data)).

You make grouping by **one** column `description` (see `groupField` in `groupingView`). So all other array parameters of `groupingView` should have one element too. Currently you use `groupColumnShow` and `groupOrder` with two elements and `groupText` with 11 (!!!) elements.

You can remove columns with `hidden:true` property (`txnID`, `isReturned`) from the grid. The input `data` of local grid still hold **all** properties. So you can use `var item = $("#jqTable").jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid)` and the `item` contains *all* properties, for example, `item.isReturned`. `getLocalRow` is much more effective as `getCell` which you use currently.

You *modify* `background-color` of some rows inside of `gridComplete`. It's ineffective (works slowly). Much more effective will be to use `rowattr` to set the required style **during** creating the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25331772/315935). By the way I would recommend you to use `loadComplete` instead of `gridComplete` if you need it. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439276/315935).

You should use `pager: "#jqTablePager"` instead of `pager: jQuery("#jqTablePager")`. Because the common error the code of jqGrid was changed some day. Now if the value of `pager` is jQuery wrapper (like `jQuery("#jqTablePager")`) jqGrid just normalize it to the selector. It get `id` of the element and fix `pager: jQuery("#jqTablePager")` to `pager: "#jqTablePager"`. But why you need first search DOM elements of the page by `id` and find DOM with `id="jqTablePager"` create jQuery wrapper to the DOM element (`jQuery("#jqTablePager")`)? It's absolutely unneeded work. You should know this and just use always `pager` in form of id selector: `"#jqTablePager"`.

Usage of `setRowData` in the loop to change `action` column of every row of the grid is slowly. Every changing of *one* element of the grid follows to reflow of *all elements of the page*. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) and [the article](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) for more details. Much more effective is to *create* the correct content of the `action` cell directly by usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). The simplest implementation which is very close to your current one will be the following

```
{ name: 'action', width: 50, align: "center", sortable: false, search: false,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
        return "<img class='icons' title='View Fee Details' src='<c:url value='/resources/img/view.png' />' onclick='viewFeeDetailPopup(" +
            options.rowId + ")'/> <img class='icons' title='View Ticket History' src='<c:url value='/resources/img/lookup2.png' />' onclick='viewTicketHistoryPopup(" +
            options.rowId + ")'/>";
    }}
```

The `rowId` property of `options` parameter provides you required information. If required you can use third `rowObject` parameter of custom formatter to access all other properties of the row item.

By the way you can consider to remove `onclick` from the above images added in `action` column and using `beforeSelectRow` callback instead. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935). You can easy modify the code to distinguish two different `img` inside of the column. `e.target` is the clicked element. The `$(e.target).attr("title")` for example will be `"View Fee Details"` in case of clicking on the first img and it will be `View Ticket History` on clicking on the second one.

The last remark. I would recommend you to reduce `colModel` which you use. You should remove all `index` properties and all properties with default values like `align: "left"`. You can include more common properties in `cmTemplate`. Using `cmTemplate: {title: false, search: false, sortable: false}` you can reduce the code and makes it more readable. The column definition

```
{ name: "priceCat", index: "priceCat", width: 100, align: "left",
    title: false, search: false, sortable: false}
```

for example will be reduced to

```
{ name: "priceCat", width: 100 }
```

The code will be smaller, more quickly loaded, more easy read, easy to maintain.

Comment: It works and thank you very much and will follow your extraordinary explanations and suggestions on my jqgrid usage. One thing is can I use `rowattr` without `css class` defined ??

Comment: @WundwinBorn: You are welcome! Yes of cause, you do can set `style` attribute directly in `rowattr` callback: `rowattr: function (item) { return item.isReturned === "true" ? {style: "background-color:orange;background-image:none"} : {};`.